# Differentiability of logistic function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I need to prove that logistic function is differentiable. I have

$f(x) = log(1 + e^{-x})$

I didnt have analysis, but I suppose I need to show that this limit exists for all points $x$:

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{log(1 + e^{-x - h}) - log(1 + e^{-x})}{h}$

But I cannot figure out how. Totally lost in algebra.

PS. Tried La'Hopital rule already when read that its circular reasoning on wiki.

Comment: See the [chain rule theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChainRule.html)